# Passing an Application Class Reference to Constructor (Java)

Tags: java, parameter-passing, actionlistener, dom-events

I have an application class, as shown directly below, which instantiates objects from i) a UI class I wrote that extends JFrame and implements ActionListener, and ii) a simple "Invoice" class.  The former will be used as a main interface that accepts text entry, for particular values ("invoice number"), and passes those values to the latter class (invoice).  I would like to extend the application class (in which main is implemented) to allow an `actionPerformed()` method to be implemented in it (not within `main()` of course) to listen to the press of one of two buttons within the UI class, creating a new instance of the Purchase class on the event, that will in turn pass a 'this' reference to the single UI class instance's `button.addActionListener()` method.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class CreatePurchase implements ActionListener {

boolean isInterface = true;
CreatePurchase testing = new CreatePurchase();
SupportiveJFrame uiFrame = new SupportiveJFrame( testing, "Southwest Invoice Systems", isInterface );   
Purchase firstPurchase = new Purchase( uiFrame, true );


public static void main( String args[] ){


}

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){

    Object source = e.getSource();

    if( source == uiFrame.newInvoice){

        //New object created here


    }

}       
}
```

My question is, How can a reference to the application class be passed to the UI constructor thereby allowing it to be passed to the JButton "newObject"?  Were I to place the initializations of "uiFrame" and "firstPurchase" in `main()`, "firstPurchase" would be out of scope from `actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the keyword `this` to get a reference to the "current instance". I'm not sure which class you want to add it to, but here's an example that should demonstrate the idea:

```
public class A {
    private B owner;
    public A(B owner) {this.owner = owner;}

    public void callOwnerDoSomething() {owner.doSomething();}
}

public class B {

    public A theA = new A(this);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().theA.callOwnerDoSomething(); // prints "Hello"
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: @AdrianM. Not really. The code I posted is only to *demonstrate* how *this* can be used; it's not supposed to be like your code. Look at `new A(this)` works, and ignore the `doSomething` and `callOwnerDoSomething` (which are just there for demonstration). `doSomething` is sort of like `actionPerformed` in your code.

Comment: The issue seems to be that if I want to pass the "firstPurchase" reference from actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ), implemented in the same place that where you have "public void doSomething()", firstPurchase" needs to be initialized outside of main().  However, because initializing this object requires having created the JFrame extending class instance, I've initialized it before "firstPurchase" - hence, before main().  This results in some kind of invalid this reference being passed to the uiFrame constructor, although no exceptions are thrown.  The program terminates immediately.